# R loop gives error (undefined columns selected) but works for the first half

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, if-statement

I want to calculate standardized t-scores, based on a raw score `Araw`, gender (male/female), and age. The standardized scores are stored in dataframes `male_a` and `female_a`. I want to select the male/female dataframe based on whether someone is male/female. In the male/female dataframe there are two columns present, indicating the standardized scores when someone is under 30 years old (column 1) or when someone is 30 and above (column 2).

After running the loop, I receive the following error `` Error in `[.data.frame`(female_a, ifelse(data$Araw[[i]] == 0,  :  undefined columns selected ``

Further inspection shows that the correct results are stored in ````tscore_a``` until row 91. From row 91 the row number is stored as result, and therefore not correct. I do not understand, because filling in e.g. row number 91 in the ifelse function gives me the correct result. Why does this loop not work properly?

```
tscore_A <- as.list(seq(1, nrow(data))) #create a empty list to store results of loop

for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  
  tscore_A[[i]] <- ifelse(data$gender[[i]] == 1, 
          male_a[ifelse(data$Araw[[i]] == 0, 0, data$Araw[[i]] + 1), ifelse(data$age[[i]] < 30, 1, 2)], 
         female_a[ifelse(data$Araw[[i]] == 0, 0, data$Araw[[i]] + 1), ifelse(data$age[[i]] < 30, 1, 2)])

}
```

```
dput(data)
structure(list(gender = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, NA, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, NA, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, NA, 2, NA, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, NA, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 2, NA, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, NA, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, NA, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, NA, NA, 2, 2, 
NA, 2, 2, NA, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, NA, NA, 2, 2, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1), age = c(29, 30, 
34, 26, 38, 33, 29, 32, 23, 31, 30, 28, 40, 29, 31, 26, 32, 28, 
33, 27, 26, 28, 25, 23, 32, 27, 30, NA, 25, 32, 27, 26, 31, 29, 
30, 30, 34, 29, 28, 23, 27, 30, 21, 29, 29, 31, 36, 32, 33, 30, 
37, 29, 23, 20, 29, 24, 31, 33, 29, 31, 23, 35, 26, 25, 23, 28, 
31, 31, 30, 28, 25, 25, 31, 31, 29, 24, 35, 26, 27, 27, 25, 25, 
33, 34, 30, 25, 31, 31, 25, 31, NA, 29, 27, 30, 29, 32, 26, 24, 
25, 27, 30, 30, 33, 29, 27, 25, 29, 30, 27, 28, 29, 27, 29, 29, 
26, 32, 36, 30, 31, 29, 26, 30, 26, 27, 28, 33, 30, 27, 28, 27, 
28, 30, 26, 25, 27, 25, 22, 35, 28, 25, 23, 37, 26, 32, 35, 30, 
27, 34, 28, 23, 32, 26, 34, 27, 34, 30, 28, 29, 25, 29, 28, 35, 
27, 25, 26, 20, 36, 27, 25, 27, 29, NA, 28, 25, 23, 33, 22, 24, 
29, 28, 25, 28, 25, 26, 33, 28, 29, 29, 23, 43, 23, 31, 31, 38, 
28, 27, 26, 28, NA, NA, 28, 23, 26, 23, 20, 31, NA, 30, 24, 30, 
26, 34, 26, 27, 28, 35, 29, 28, 27, 26, 35, 30, 35, 25, 30, 36, 
36, 25, 27, 26, 26, 31, 27, 34, 31, 32, 31, 32, 23, 32, 33, 32, 
NA, NA, 29, 33), Araw = c(6, 0, 9, 7, 7, 6, 4, 12, 13, 
11, 1, 10, 4, 6, 5, 3, 9, 4, 6, 4, 10, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 0, 9, 6, 
8, 10, 7, 7, 4, 10, 5, 12, 6, 8, NA, 6, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 
0, 8, 4, 9, 3, 8, 5, 10, 2, 10, 3, 5, 10, 7, 8, 5, 5, 8, 6, 8, 
8, 5, 4, 5, 6, 0, 8, 6, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 13, 12, 4, 3, 0, 
7, 7, 5, 5, 1, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 4, 6, 6, 5, 6, 2, 9, 1, 5, 13, 
4, 7, 8, 12, 7, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 6, 11, 4, 6, 5, 3, 7, 2, 
6, 10, 4, 8, 8, 6, 9, NA, NA, 9, 6, 8, 8, 7, 4, 4, 4, 8, 11, 
9, 6, 9, 6, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 0, 1, 7, 10, 7, 5, 4, 4, 11, 5, 
12, 2, 10, 13, 8, 6, 7, 5, 8, 8, NA, 3, 9, 1, 5, 9, 11, 11, 4, 
5, 7, NA, 12, 5, 6, 2, 7, 12, 4, 8, 1, 11, NA, 5, 8, 6, 7, 10, 
8, 9, 6, 5, 9, NA, NA, 4, 7, NA, 8, 6, NA, 11, 5, 7, 3, 1, 6, 
7, 6, 10, NA, 5, 6, 9, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 11, 7, 7, 6, NA, NA, 
NA, 4, NA, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -246L
))


dput(male_a)
structure(list(X1 = c(35L, 37L, 39L, 42L, 45L, 48L, 51L, 54L, 
57L, 60L, 63L, 66L, 69L, 72L, 75L, 78L), X2 = c(36L, 40L, 42L, 
45L, 49L, 52L, 55L, 59L, 62L, 66L, 69L, 73L, 76L, 79L, 83L, 86L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 0:15)

dput(female_a)
structure(list(X1 = c(36L, 39L, 41L, 44L, 47L, 51L, 54L, 57L, 
61L, 64L, 67L, 70L, 74L, 77L, 80L, 83L), X2 = c(36L, 39L, 42L, 
45L, 49L, 52L, 56L, 59L, 63L, 66L, 70L, 73L, 77L, 80L, 84L, 87L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 0:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some missing data that seems to be messing up the indexing.  If you just put in an `if()` condition that only evaluates the expression when the relevant parts are observed, it works.

```r
tscore_A <- as.list(seq(1, nrow(data))) #create a empty list to store results of loop
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(!is.na(data$gender[[i]]) & !is.na(data$Araw[[i]]) & !is.na(data$age[[i]])){
  tscore_A[[i]] <- ifelse(data$gender[[i]] == 1, 
                          male_a[ifelse(data$Araw[[i]] == 0, 0, data$Araw[[i]] + 1), ifelse(data$age[[i]] < 30, 1, 2)], 
                          female_a[ifelse(data$Araw[[i]] == 0, 0, data$Araw[[i]] + 1), ifelse(data$age[[i]] < 30, 1, 2)])
  }else{
    tscore_A[[i]] <- NA
  }  
}
head(tscore_A)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 51
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 66
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 54
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 59
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 56
```